# for loop in R comparison

Tags: r, for-loop

The following piece of code does exactly what I need. However, for exercise purposes, I cannot use the `rep` function.

```
for (i in 1:4){
  print(paste(rep(LETTERS[i], i), collapse = ""))
}
```

- [1] "A"
- [1] "BB"
- [1] "CCC"
- [1] "DDDD"

So I attempted the following:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  for (j in 1:i) {
    print(paste(LETTERS[i]))
  }
  cat('\n')
}
```

- [1] "A"
- [1] "B"
- [1] "B"
- [1] "C"
- [1] "C"
- [1] "C"
- [1] "D"
- [1] "D"
- [1] "D"
- [1] "D"

which isn't quite the output that I'm going for. I tried transposing within the inner for loop all to no avail. Can someone please help here?

Comment: To recreate `rep(LETTERS[i],i)` without `rep()` you would need to create an empty vector of length `i` before your `j` inner loop begins. Then assign `LETTERS[i]` to each element of that vector, which you can do in your inner loop. Or you could "cheat" and use the `replicate()` function ... hey they only said you couldn't use `rep()`, didn't say anything about `replicate()` :-D

Comment: did your exercise say anything about `strrep`? `strrep(LETTERS[1:4], 1:4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential solution would be to add each letter to a vector then print the vector after each "j" loop and clear the vector, e.g.

```r
output <- c()
for (i in 1:4) {
  for (j in 1:i) {
   output <- paste0(output, LETTERS[i])
  }
  print(output)
  output <- c()
}
#> [1] "A"
#> [1] "BB"
#> [1] "CCC"
#> [1] "DDDD"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Edit

Per @thelatemail's comment, you should avoid 'growing' a vector in the 'lazy' way I suggested above, as performance is terrible. A much better option is to pre-allocate the vector then fill it with letters, then collapse the output e.g.

```r
for (i in 1:4) {
  out <- vector("character", i)
  for (j in 1:i) {
    out[j] <- LETTERS[i]
  }
  print(paste(out, collapse=""))
}
#> [1] "A"
#> [1] "BB"
#> [1] "CCC"
#> [1] "DDDD"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or use a list to store the output, e.g.

```r
output <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  for (j in 1:i) {
    output[[j]] <- LETTERS[i]
  }
  print(paste(output, collapse=""))
}
#> [1] "A"
#> [1] "BB"
#> [1] "CCC"
#> [1] "DDDD"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I'd avoid the growing of the vector. You know the size of the output so you can pre-allocate - `out <- vector("character", i)` in the outer loop then `out[j] <- LETTERS[i]` in the inner, then `print(paste(out, collapse=""))` in the outer again.

Comment: You are absolutely right @thelatemail, I'll edit my answer